# process cannot access file because it is being used by another process

Tags: java, file, nio, file-writing

Though there are lot of questions like this on stackoverflow, but for me it is giving error while writing very fast to file, this method is called around 180 times in a minutes to write data to file. and when frequency of writing is very fast then it gives error as :

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\dropcopy\DGCX_Report_Files\TradeReport_18072018.csv: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:86)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:230)
at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:434)
at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:216)
at java.nio.file.Files.write(Files.java:3292)
at com.algo.fix.common.TradeFileManager.appendInFile(TradeFileManager.java:542)
at com.algo.fix.common.TradeFileManager.persistExecutions(TradeFileManager.java:469)
at com.algo.fix.common.TradeFileManager.processTradeCaptureReport(TradeFileManager.java:768)
at com.algo.fix.common.BaseApplication.onMessage(BaseApplication.java:129)
at quickfix.fix50sp2.MessageCracker.crack11(MessageCracker.java:253)
at quickfix.fix50sp2.MessageCracker.crack(MessageCracker.java:217)
at com.algo.fix.common.BaseApplication.fromApp(BaseApplication.java:97)
at quickfix.Session.fromCallback(Session.java:1818)
at quickfix.Session.verify(Session.java:1762)
at quickfix.Session.verify(Session.java:1833)
at quickfix.Session.next(Session.java:1030)
at quickfix.Session.next(Session.java:1173)
at quickfix.mina.SingleThreadedEventHandlingStrategy$SessionMessageEvent.processMessage(SingleThreadedEventHandlingStrategy.java:151)
at quickfix.mina.SingleThreadedEventHandlingStrategy.block(SingleThreadedEventHandlingStrategy.java:101)
at quickfix.mina.SingleThreadedEventHandlingStrategy.lambda$blockInThread$0(SingleThreadedEventHandlingStrategy.java:133)
at quickfix.mina.SingleThreadedEventHandlingStrategy$ThreadAdapter$RunnableWrapper.run(SingleThreadedEventHandlingStrategy.java:244)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

but after this error , it resumes again to writing. skipping some data to file.
my code to write to file is :

```
try{
        String data = sb.toString();
        byte[] dataByte= data.getBytes();
        Files.write(file, dataByte, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);                              
        Files.write(file, System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        log.info("Wrote to file.");
    } catch(Exception e ){
        log.info("Not able to write to file.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: `Files.write` is opening the, writing the data and then closing, so in you example code, that's two open/close operations in that block alone.  You might consider using a producer/consumer approach to buffer the output and take manual control over the opening/closing of the file. For example, while there is data in the buffer, open the file and write to it (with possibly periodical flushes), when there is no data, close the file and wait for more data.  You might also consider putting a synchronised block around it so other one thread and perform the operation at a time - as some ideas

Comment: Opening and closing a file is very expensive. If you were to keep the file open you should find you can write many 100k/s

Comment: @PeterLawrey but what if my file remains open and writing and another write comes? then it wont be able to write. Is is safe to do so? and also if i am using nio files how can stop it from closing

Comment: You should have one program write to the file and if you have concurrent threads writing, hold a lock while you do it.  I suggest you write to the FileOutputStream directly and close it when you are finished.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using two threads `Producer and Consumer`.
One thread which was generating the data to write in the file was putting those data objects to `LinkedBlockingQueue` and another thread was fetching data from this queue using `take`() method and persisting data objects into the file.

Advantage of using `LinkedBlockingQueue` over others is that it provides  `take`() method which retrieves and removes the `head` of this `queue` waiting if necessary until an element becomes available and `put()` method which waits until necessary space is available.